# Program is terminated from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium

The error message is throwing when executing a Java *TestNG* program in Eclipse Error:

```
Could not find or load main class intranetWC.home
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: We can do nothing without seeing the code you are executing **and** the full error **and** the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when you use command line tools. Try to clean the project or your whole workspace.

If that doesn't help, make sure the classpath is correct a.k.a "what you expect" (you can see it in the properties of the process in the debug perspective).